# Generic type extending union is not narrowed by type guard

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I tried to replicate Anders' example for conditional types and generics which he showed at [Build 2018](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2018/BRK2150) (36:45). He uses a conditional type as a return type as replacement for more traditional function overloads.

The slide has the following:

```
type Name = { name: string };
type Id = { id: number };
type Check = { enabled: boolean };

type LabelForType<T> =
  T extends string ? Name :
  T extends number ? Id :
  T extends boolean ? Check :
  never;

declare function createLabel<T extends string | number | boolean>(value: T): LabelForType<T>
```

I tried to simplify this a bit and came up with the following example. The conditional type returns `number` when given a `string` and vice versa, while the function implements this conditional type as return type.

```
type Return<T> = T extends string ? number : T extends number ? string : never;

function typeSwitch<T extends string | number>(x: T):  Return<T>{
  if (typeof x == "string") {
    return 42;
  } else if (typeof x == "number") {
    return "Hello World!";
  }
  throw new Error("Invalid input"); // needed because TS return analysis doesn't currently factor in complete control flow analysis
}

const x = typeSwitch("qwerty"); // number
```

However both return statements show the same error:

```
Type '42' is not assignable to type 'Return<T>'.(2322)
Type '"Hello World!"' is not assignable to type 'Return<T>'.(2322)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's why it doesn't work: Typescript does [control-flow type narrowing](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeScript-New-Handbook/chapters/narrowing/) on regular variables, but not on *type variables* like your `T`. The type guard `typeof x === "string"` can be used to narrow the variable `x` to type `string`, but it cannot narrow `T` to be `string`, and does not try.

This makes sense, because `T` could be the union type `string | number` even when `x` is a string, so it would be unsound to narrow `T` itself, or to narrow `T`'s upper bound. In theory it would be sound to narrow `T` to something like *"a type which extends `string | number` but whose intersection with `string` is not `never`"*, but that would add an awful lot of complexity to the type system for relatively little gain. There is no fully general way around this except to use type assertions; for example, in your code, `return 42 as Return<T>;`.

That said, in your use-case you don't need a generic function at all; you can just write two [overload signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```js
// overload signatures
function typeSwitch(x: string): number;
function typeSwitch(x: number): string;
// implementation
function typeSwitch(x: string | number): string | number {
  if (typeof x === "string") {
    return 42;
  } else {
    // typeof x === "number" here
    return "Hello World!";
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEHsDcFMCcBtwEMAmoDOBLA5gOyQC4Cus06AUAGZG4DGBm4uoBAngA7QDKA7pgbQAWACgAeALgwFYmXNgCUk3EQC2AIzgBuKjXqNmbTr35CxS1RtiKpMudpChMK9vGgrouAoX066DJiwc3HwCIhI2stigAD6gyupw1ujSkTFxFnCgAN7koI6UoMKG0OAFoqAAvFWgAETJttg18tm5eaCkxLDMACwATNp5AL6g0PDo0C1toA7FpaDlVRW18ZY1oIJw0K15HSTMNQASo4igAOrgCCgAhDUDoIPkD+S0TMnzlYFGIaY1AI48cDYTU00zAKzg5CAA)

Comment: The question is, why does it work in the video? The OPs code is *almost* straight copied from the presentation slides and Anders specifically states that you don't need overloads. And indeed, if I do copy the slide code the compiler accepts it, but there's no concrete implementation on the slides.

Comment: Well, in the video there is no function implementation, therefore no code that *could* have this error in it... so of course it doesn't have the same error as the OP's code. But as I said, you could write it as a generic function if you use type assertions.

Comment: Maybe this is my lack of understanding talking, but if I have to assert to the compiler that things are in fact the types I know them to be, then what's the point of all of this? Is it any more type-safe than me just writing a plain old function with a switch statement and asserting the return type? What does all of this buy us?

Comment: @JaredSmith Type safety means that a type annotation is never violated - if an expression has compile-type Foo, then type safety means its value at runtime is always assignable to Foo. Using a type assertion is perfectly type-safe if your assertion is correct. In this case, if you assert `return 42 as Return<T>;` then that assertion is correct, it's just that the compiler doesn't have a rule that would allow it to determine that 42 is of type `Return<T>` by itself.

Comment: As for *"what's the point"*, your options are between having a type-checker which proves *most* of your code is safe (and most of the time, correctly tells you when your code isn't safe), or not having a type-checker. It is computationally impossible to have a type-checker that can prove all type-safe code to be type-safe, but hardly useless to have a type-checker that occasionally needs you to fill in a couple of gaps in its own proof. Typescript doesn't prove every provable property of your code, and isn't trying to, and isn't advertised as trying to.

Comment: Nevermind I get it now. I was trying to assert the *specific* return type, not just `Return<T>`. Makes sense. Hopefully the OP will find it as useful as I did.

Comment: Ah; good point, yes, it won't work if you write `return 42 as number;` (or the equivalent `return 42 as Return<string>;`), and of course you should never (and do never) need to assert that 42 is a number.

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks, I didn't think about the lack of control-flow type narrowing on type variables. However in the explanation, I don't understand why "`T` could be the union type `string | number` even when `x` is a `string`". Regarding type assertion, I am with @JaredSmith in that I think it makes no sense if I have to give the guarantees that the types are what they are as this is what TS is for. Also, I actually used my example code with overloads before, but upon watching Anders example, I thought this could be shortened using conditional types. I guess it's not that easy, at least not yet.

Comment: @philmcole `T` is a type, and `x` has a value; they are related by the fact that `x`'s value must be assignable to `T`, but they are not related by equality or equivalence. It's perfectly possible that your function is called like `typeSwitch<string | number>("hello")`, in which case `T = string | number` and `typeof x === "string"`. Or your function could be called from another function with an argument whose compile-time type is `string | number` but whose value at runtime is a string.

Comment: As for *"I think it makes no sense if I have to give the guarantees that the types are what they are"*, I think you are missing the point; the assertion `42 as Return<T>` is not asserting that the type of `42` "is what it is". The type of 42 is `number`, which is not the same as `Return<T>`, and not always assignable to `Return<T>` depending on what `T` is. It just happens in this case that we humans can prove that `42` is assignable to `Return<T>` whenever that `if` condition is true, whereas Typescript cannot prove it. Typescript can still prove most of what you want it to, just not that.

Comment: @philmcole The alternative is that you write overloads for every single signature, which is cumbersome, or you abandon type safety.