# TypeScript generic with two parents cannot be fully eliminated by one type guard

Tags: typescript

Can somebody be as kind as to explain to me why the below code makes the TypeScript compiler think that even when I've eliminated one of the only two possibilities (as far as I understand this), it is not enough?

Is this a bug in TS, or me? :)

Cheers

```
interface One {
  one: "ONE"
}

interface Two {
  two: "TWO";
}

function func<T extends (One|Two)>(i: T) {
  function isOne(item: T): item is T & One{
    return !!(item as One).one;
  }

  if(isOne(i)) {
    return i;
  }

  return i.two; // Why does it expect i to still be "extends (One|Two)"
}
```

The code is simplified from its original version (there are more parameters that revolve around `T`, `One` and `Two`), however, the reason why I got to ask this question is because when I do it "the right way" and have one more type guard for `Two`, I end up having to put there a default clause, which as far as I understand can NEVER happen. What's wrong with my understanding of this?

```
interface One {
  one: "ONE"
}

interface Two {
  two: "TWO";
}

function func<T extends (One|Two)>(i: T) {
  function isOne(item: T): item is T & One {
    return !!(item as One).one;
  }

  if(isOne(i)) {
    return i;
  }

  function isTwo(item: T): item is T & Two {
    return !!(item as Two).two;
  }

  if(isTwo(i)) {
    return i.two
  }

  return; // WTF, how can I ever get here?
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic type extending union is not narrowed by type guard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60475431/12299000)

Comment: Hey. Thanks for digging that up. It seems similar, but I am more confused than I was :)

So, is my assumption that the last line in my second example function can never really be reached? If so, is having a silly-looking throw Error statement the only way to alleviate the compulsion the compiler has for having a return there?

Comment: Hey. Thanks for digging that up. It seems similar, but I am more confused than I was :)

So, is my assumption that the last line in my second example function can never really be reached? If so, is having a silly-looking throw Error statement the only way to alleviate the compulsion the compiler has for having a return there?

The second point is; why the heck cannot “T extends One|Two” be fully eliminated by checking it for being “T & One” and “T & Two”? What else could it possibly be then these two?

What is the thing that I am missing? With colors and pictures, if you please :D

Comment: I am sorry for the comment looking so bad. I am editing it on my phone and besides having to be super careful about pressing enter (which even on the phone auto submits) the white spaces I put there for brewery were completely ignored. Sniff.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, in the first example your last line `return i.two;` is type-safe, and in your second example your last line `return;` is unreachable, but Typescript isn't able to figure it out in either case, because instead of a union type `One | Two`, you have a generic type `T` extending a union type. Unfortunately Typescript doesn't do narrowing properly in this situation; I created [a related issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36772) last month on their issue tracker, which is currently open as a bug and marked as to be fixed in version 3.9.1.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. Looking at the issue your reported to the TS team, i am not sure if fixing it would necessarily fix this issue that I’m having, would it?

Comment: It's difficult to say for sure whether it would or wouldn't, but if the bug is fixed in a way that doesn't solve it for your exact code then at least there will likely be a way to rewrite the code to do what you want.

Comment: Well, let’s see. What are you thinking about when you say, possibly rewrite?