# Type Narrowing not working as expected with generic constraints

Tags: typescript, union-types, generic-constraints, type-narrowing

I have a situation where the generic type is constraint by a union type, but I find that doing this does not make the type narrowing to work as expected. The code snippet below shows what is going on.

```
function somefunc<T extends string | number>(input: T): T {
  if (typeof input === "string") {
    // expecting input to be of type "string"
    // but input becomes of type T & "string"
    input
  } else {
    // expecting input to be of type "number"
    // but input becomes of type T extends string | number
    input
 }
}
```

If I do away with the generics and just annotate the function argument as `string | number` it works, but for my use case I need to have the generic constraints.

**Edit**

The use case is basically an attempt to also use this with conditional types. Basically I want to have a result type be a conditional type that depends on the input type. So when the input type is `number`, the result is also `number`, when input is `string` result becomes `string` also. Basically this:

```
type Result<T> = T extends string ? string : number

function somefunc<T extends string | number>(input: T): Result<T> {
  if (typeof input === "string") {
    // expecting input to be of type "string"
    // but input becomes of type T & "string"
    input
  } else {
    // expecting input to be of type "number"
    // but input becomes of type T extends string | number
    input
 }
}
```

I am probably missing something, but the question is, how do I have union based generic constraint and have type narrowing work as I expect. In the above code, that will mean, in the `if` branch, `input` becomes type `string` while in the `else` branch, it becomes `number` (or at least it becomes `T & number`)

** Edit **

I was able to achieve want I wanted using function overloading. I was only wondering if same thing can be achieved using generics and conditional types.

Comment: That's because with generics, your `somefunc` method will accept anything on top of string or number types. If you know that `input` must be of string or number, can't you simply do `function somefunc(input: string | number): string | number`?

Comment: updated the question to provide more information

Comment: If the else branch becomes of type `T & number` then that is still go, similar to how the if branch is `T & string`. but right now the else is T extends string | number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it's not narrowed is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60476282/12397250)

Hacky way to narrow the type correctly:

```
type Result<T> = T extends string ? string : number;

function somefunc<T extends string | number>(input: T): Result<T> {
  const inputNarrowed: string | number = input;

  if (typeof inputNarrowed === "string") {
    inputNarrowed; // string
  } else {
    inputNarrowed; // number
  }

  return inputNarrowed as Result<T>;
}
```

---

Alternative solution (which I prefer) with overload + conditional generic

```
type Result<T> = T extends string ? string : number;

function somefunc<T extends string | number>(input: T): Result<T>;
function somefunc(input: string | number) {
  if (typeof input === "string") {
    input; // string
  } else {
    input; // number
  }

  return input;
}

const str = somefunc("string"); // string
const num = somefunc(1); // number
```

Comment: I had to do some casting in the return expression though...eg `return inputNarrowed as Result<T>;` is that how it should be?

Comment: Yes, however this is not caused by the `inputNarrowed`. Simple function like `const fun = <T extends string | number>(input: T): Result<T> => input;` still requires you to cast the return type because the return type is `Result<T>`, not `T`

Comment: I added an alternative solution which might interest you, it still uses overloading, but also uses generic type for the function interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to narrow to exact type, consider next example:

```js
function somefunc(input: number): number
function somefunc(input: string): string
function somefunc(input: string | number): string | number {
  if (typeof input === "string") {
    return input // stirng
  } else {
    return input // number
  }
}


const x = somefunc(10)
```

Drawback: no generics )

Comment: Yup. Already have the function overloading working...wanted to see if it is possible with a combination of generics and conditional types :)

Comment: Btw, you can call `input.toString()` to make it strictly `string` instead of `T & string`