# Unable to narrow generic type extending union

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a generic function that groups list items from a discriminated union, without caring about the other attributes of the items. Typescript seems to be unable to narrow the generic union type.

Looking through typescript [issues](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) and [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#contextual-narrowing-for-generics), it seems like this should work. The examples in the docs certainly do.

I know that I can use a type assertion to work around this, but I'd prefer not to lose type safety within the function.

stripped-down code in question:

```
type ParagraphBlocklike = {
  type: 'paragraph';
};

type BulletedListItemBlocklike = {
  type: 'bulleted-list-item';
};

type Blocklike =
  | ParagraphBlocklike
  | BulletedListItemBlocklike
;

type BulletedListRenderNode<B extends BulletedListItemBlocklike> = {
  type: 'bulleted-list';
  items: B[]
};


type RenderNode<B extends Blocklike> =
  | (Exclude<B, BulletedListItemBlocklike>)
  | BulletedListRenderNode<Extract<B, BulletedListItemBlocklike>>;


const fnConvert = <B extends Blocklike>(block: B): RenderNode<B> => {
  if(block.type === 'bulleted-list-item') {
    
    // type of block: B extends Blocklike
    return {type: 'bulleted-list', items: [block]};
    /*
Type '{ type: "bulleted-list"; items: B[]; }' is not assignable to type 'RenderNode<B>'.
  Types of property 'items' are incompatible.
    Type 'B[]' is not assignable to type 'Extract<B, BulletedListItemBlocklike>[]'.
      Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'Extract<B, BulletedListItemBlocklike>'.
        Type 'Blocklike' is not assignable to type 'Extract<B, BulletedListItemBlocklike>'.
          Type 'ParagraphBlocklike' is not assignable to type 'Extract<B, BulletedListItemBlocklike>'.
    */
  }

  // type: B extends Blocklike
  return block;

  /*
Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'RenderNode<B>'.
  Type 'Blocklike' is not assignable to type 'RenderNode<B>'.
    Type 'ParagraphBlocklike' is not assignable to type 'RenderNode<B>'.
      Type 'ParagraphBlocklike' is not assignable to type 'Exclude<B, BulletedListItemBlocklike>'.
        Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'BulletedListRenderNode<Extract<B, BulletedListItemBlocklike>>'.
          Type 'Blocklike' is not assignable to type 'BulletedListRenderNode<Extract<B, BulletedListItemBlocklike>>'.
            Property 'items' is missing in type 'ParagraphBlocklike' but required in type 'BulletedListRenderNode<Extract<B, BulletedListItemBlocklike>>'
  */
};
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgcyWAFgIQDYHsDGA1tgJaHQC8UA3gFBRSiQBcUA5GIimumwNy0AvgNpNomAK7ZsEYBAAmAGRIBnYAEk5AWxwFiZSjXqNwEVmwBGUmXPkBaUmrslt-ISLFRdRUuSgVjAB9YLlQ4DG99ciCva1kFZTVNCB08HwNaD1NY6XilVWAAJQgAO3kIBAA5XHKAHkwoCAAPOTKVHJsEguTUvV8IAD5-IwYxcytc2wcCtwYXFJVWTABtAF13Wk3PYrKK6rqG5tb5dsj+oYCGYIAKAFEm-GwJA4AaDrzEjW0zgwGAShikkmXTUO3KVRqEFq92ASHwwHqbyBnXySW+aSigwGInwuBKaigADMSgBhPEANwqwBJcAJVHqjRapROXgx52uFgxSz+rDBe0h9QuQzoc0JHIxADpPBQZewJijpk55lo2H8RgwoJy9MYGAhZBIECUaGM5XEpo5gGw3srFlBllqiFBaVAYXCEZgkWaQV8Uj9yANVsJjIJNrr9YbNRine17o9nlCPe9bJ8en7BgIg7RcfjgETSRSqcMGUdmac2b9xXpubzmfyDkL1SQxQ7CFLsjKqJYvfYLc5XGqRRqWzqoHrgAajdQTV3gT2ZtbtLb7RjAwIGCHjGOJ5G9Bm+EA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic type extending union is not narrowed by type guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60475431/generic-type-extending-union-is-not-narrowed-by-type-guard)

Comment: The contextual narrowing for generics in TS4.3+ narrows *values* (like `block`) of conditional types depending on unspecified generic type parameters, but it does not narrow *the type parameters themselves*. You can check `block.type` all you like but it won't do anything to `B`. There is a feature request at [ms/TS#33912](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) asking for something better, but who knows if it'll ever be implemented. For now you pretty much need to use something like type assertions [as in this code](//tsplay.dev/WYBKgw) to sidestep the problem.

Comment: If that clears things up for you I can write up an answer expanding on it.  If there's still something unclear about it, or if I didn't address the question properly, please let me know.

Comment: @jcalz. I am seeing how some of what I've written here matches the linked issue and SO post, but not fully understanding what isn't working. Is it that `block`'s type is narrowed in the `else` to `ParagraphBlocklike`, but typescript isn't able to recognize that returning `block` satisfies `RenderNode<Blocklike>`?

If I remove the explicit return type on `fnConvert`, ts infers the return as `B | { type: string; items: B[]; }`, as opposed to `Exclude<B, BulletedListItemBlocklike> | { type: string; items: BulletedListItemBlockLike[]; }`. Is this what the linked issue is referring to?

Comment: Hmm, The fundamental problem is that the compiler can't really do too much higher-order type juggling with unresolved conditional types like `B` inside the body of `fnConvert()`.  It mostly just *defers* evaluation unless the types are obviously and immediately equivalent.  I mean, I could probably say "hey what if `B` is `{type: "paragraph" | "bulleted-list-item"}`, then `RenderNode<B>` is like `{ type: "paragraph" | "bulleted-list-item"} | BulletedListRenderNode<never>` and `[block]` is not of type `never[]`, so the compiler is "technically correct" to complain, but the truth is (1/2)

Comment: that the compiler simply could not see if those two types were the same even if there is no subtype of `Blocklike` that invalidates your assumptions.  The only reasonable way forward is to use a type assertion and move on.  If, in the future, the compiler gets better about evaluating the effect of checking values on type parameters, so that such generic-conditional function implementations are more ergonomic, then maybe that will change.  But for now that's the way it is.  Does that make sense now or is there something else missing for you?  (2/2)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. Are you saying that `B` could be `{type: "paragraph" | "bulleted-list-item"}`, which would satisfy `B extends Blocklike` but wouldn't work with the `Extract` in the definition of `RenderNode`? Which is to say that my types are not defined in a way that prevents these invalid cases?

And, even if they were, the compiler (without the linked feature request) would be unable to see that the types are equivalent?

Comment: Is it accurate to say that, even though ts can see that `block` in the branch is `BulletedListItemBlocklike`, it's not able to see that `{type: 'bulleted-list', items: [block]}` is `RenderNode<B>`, because it's not able to see that `BulletedListItemBlocklike` is `Extract<B, BulletedListItemBlocklike>`?