# Returning a Partial from a predefined Union of objects

Tags: typescript

Can anyone give me some intuition about these error messages?

```
type States = {type: "a", data: string} | {type: "b", data: number};

function getPartial<S extends States>(state: S) : Partial<S> {
  if (state.type === "a") {
    return {data: "foo"};
    // Error: Type '{ data: "foo"; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<S>'.
  }
  return {data: 2};
  // Error: Type '{ data: 2; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<S>'.
};
```

It feels like it should work!

Comment: The idea is that type narrowing happens on the **variable**, not on the type itself.

Comment: The answer is that [Typescript does control-flow type narrowing on regular variables, but not on type variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60475431/generic-type-extending-union-is-not-narrowed-by-type-guard/60476282#60476282). Thanks, Blackhole, for comments above.